# 401 (Unauthorized) when subscribing to private-channel in Pusher (Vue/Laravel)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, websocket, pusher, pusher-js

I've set up a `Vue3/Laravel` app with a live-chat via `Pusher` which works over non-private channel `chat`. In the next step I want to use a private channel but something weird happens. The `pusher.subscribe` function that tries to send a request to `/api/pusher/auth` doesn't seem to handle the `sanctum authorization` correctly, resulting in:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/api/pusher/auth 401 (Unauthorized)
ajax @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:676
(anonymous) @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:3548
authorize @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:1860
subscribe @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:1828
subscribe @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:3960
subscribeAll @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:3951
(anonymous) @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:3868
emit @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:1230
updateState @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:2341
connected @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:2281
callback @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:2176
cb @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:2619
tryNextStrategy @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:2459
(anonymous) @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:2507
(anonymous) @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:3399
finish @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:1752
onMessage @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:1729
emit @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:1230
onMessage @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:1327
socket.onmessage @ pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:1343
Show 20 more frames
Show less
pusher-js.js?v=1974b27b:979 Pusher :  : ["Error: Unable to retrieve auth string from channel-authorization endpoint - received status: 401 from http://localhost:8000/api/pusher/auth. Clients must be authorized to join private or presence channels. See: https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authorizing-users/"]
```

This problem is specific to the `pusher` route, all other api routes work just fine.

## Frontend setup

**pusher.js**:

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js'

Pusher.logToConsole = true

const pusher = new Pusher('bf29be46d8eb2ea8ccd4', {
  cluster: 'eu',
  forceTLS: true,
  authEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/api/pusher/auth',
  withCredentials: true,
  wsPort: 443,
  wssPort: 443,
  enableStats: false,
  enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
  auth: {
    headers: {
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    },
  }
})

export default pusher
```

**axios.js**:

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

if (import.meta.env.DEV) {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000'
}
```

the user is authenticated in a login component:

```
const signIn = () => {
  axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(() => {
    axios
      .post('/login', form)
      .then(() => {
        store.auth = sessionStorage.auth = 1
        store.signInModal = false
      })
      .catch((er) => {
        state.errors = er.response.data.errors
      })
  })
}
```

and the app tries to subscribe to pusher in a chat component, only accessible to authenticated users:

```
const inquireChatSession = () => {
  axios
    .get(`/api/chat/${props.id}`)
    .then((res) => {
      state.chatSessionId = res.data.id
      state.messages = res.data.messages
      state.loadingSession = false

      const channel = pusher.subscribe(`private-chat.${state.chatSessionId}`) // 401 happens here

      channel.bind('App\\Events\\ChatMessageSent', (data) => {
        state.messages.push(data.chatMessage)
      })
    })
    .catch((er) => {
      state.errors = er.response.data.errors
      state.loadingSession = false
    })
}
```

## Backend setup

**/routes/api.php**:

```
Route::post('/pusher/auth', function (Request $request) {
    \Log::info('test');

    $user = $request->user();
    if (!$user) {
        abort(403, 'Unauthorized');
    }

    $pusher = new Pusher(
        env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        ['cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER')]
    );

    $channelName = $request->channel_name;
    $socketId = $request->socket_id;

    $auth = $pusher->socket_auth($channelName, $socketId);

    return response()->json(['auth' => $auth]);
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

pusher is trying to connect to this route but the authorization fails, resulting in `'test'` not being logged and returning aforementioned error back to the client. This seems to be a `vue spa + pusher + sanctum` problem because connecting to this diagnostic route works:

```
Route::post('/pusher/auth', function (Request $request) {
    \Log::info(var_export($request, true));
    \Log::info('Request headers: ', $request->header());
    \Log::info('Request cookies: ', $request->cookies->all());
    \Log::info('Session data: ', $request->session()->all());
    \Log::info('User: ', $request->user());
})
```

but `$request->cookies->all()` is empty and `$request->user()` is `null`. For some reason no `auth cookies` are arriving in the pusher route. To check if `sanctum` works by itself, connecting to the following route, returns the authorized user:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/test-auth', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

relevant **.env** entries:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost

PUSHER_APP_ID=1728518
PUSHER_APP_KEY=bf29be46d8eb2ea8ccd4
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=...
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=eu
```

like I said, the entire authentication of the app works fine except the pusher route.

## Browser Network Tab

**auth request #1**:

General:

```
Request URL:       http://localhost:8000/api/pusher/auth
Request Method:    OPTIONS
Status Code:       204 No Content
Remote Address:    127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy:   strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:    true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:        POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:         http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Max-Age:              0
Cache-Control:                       no-cache, private
Connection:                          close
Content-Type:                        text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:                                Wed, 27 Dec 2023 02:25:13 GMT
Host:                                localhost:8000
Vary:                                Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Powered-By:                        PHP/8.3.1
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept:                            */*
Accept-Encoding:                   gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:                   en-GB,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:    x-requested-with
Access-Control-Request-Method:     POST
Cache-Control:                     no-cache
Connection:                        keep-alive
Host:                              localhost:8000
Origin:                            http://localhost:3000
Pragma:                            no-cache
Referer:                           http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest:                    empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:                    cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:                    same-site
User-Agent:                        Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

followed by **auth request #2**:

General:

```
Request URL:        http://localhost:8000/api/pusher/auth
Request Method:     POST
Status Code:        401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:     127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy:    strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:    true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:         http://localhost:3000
Cache-Control:                       no-cache, private
Connection:                          close
Content-Type:                        application/json
Date:                                Wed, 27 Dec 2023 02:25:13 GMT
Host:                                localhost:8000
Set-Cookie:                          XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Inl5T2ZLbndpZG1OUTV5MmxNdDlNNWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUzdJYVkzZzJvM3FnaUlIUGxVWFBDTTZYeHQveTBWOWoxSEsvcThGM00wVDh6WExmK2RYWVBldTNxK2xKS1RrV1JSTHA2b0NEMVFtQzlzSmxyVVVRbmlrSmNRdmJQaW00cWpIQVFyZkhYM0RwampuMDZWVzJsV3NUZjVJZ1kxaG0iLCJtYWMiOiI4MzFlZjBjYWZkNDZkZDBhMGYxZDgwMDQ5YTgzY2ExNDg1NDMyNjFlNTNmZDg5NGJmZTI4MDMxNzAzMjVlNjZjIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Wed, 27 Dec 2023 04:25:13 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=localhost; samesite=lax
Set-Cookie: soul_meatcom_session=eyJpdiI6Ii8wTktnTVFMZUZBYXVTeTFTRjd4dmc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoicDUzNjFJVEYyTVR5cXdrTGZQZWZ1NzF4UEZ6QUJXSWF3YUsya0lUZy9qb0IwNk0rM0cwa3RwV1YyZ1Q0T0JqWW90cjZKd2d3OXNqOW13aGswc2tPMGw0d0hPRkxDZDdqamFUQWpKSktVd2ZpS1c2b3NqQm5WMVhoK2VsLzJWeEkiLCJtYWMiOiI4YjM3ZWEwZWMwNzlhNDIxMWNhNjBhMjAzNzcxNDM0NGMxNTczOTU1YWQ0ZGFjNzEyYWJkNDI2ZWJiNjI2ZTZkIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Wed, 27 Dec 2023 04:25:13 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=localhost; httponly; samesite=lax
X-Powered-By:                        PHP/8.3.1
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept:                   */*
Accept-Encoding:          gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:          en-GB,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8
Cache-Control:            no-cache
Connection:               keep-alive
Content-Length:           87
Content-Type:             application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:                     localhost:8000
Origin:                   http://localhost:3000
Pragma:                   no-cache
Referer:                  http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Ch-Ua:                "Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:         ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:       "macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:           empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:           cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:           same-site
User-Agent:               Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:         XMLHttpRequest
```

## Browser Application Tab

there are two cookies in **/storage/cookies/http://localhost:3000**:

#1 soul_meatcom_session:

```
eyJpdiI6ImI4dUNWL0pCRmRibFMzNUdyT0JrL3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQTN4L0djZm52bjlCSFV4TmM0QU1oNUFoT0JBUlFGcGNWMFVwSDEvTFZBWmZwVi9kSEFnUitHcit6MzRLNXVkNkxLU1o5a0VhWmJ2OTNvYUdxMkpyVDVUcVZoQWRzckVlVi84Tis3UTdxazhkR0ozU1EyeldnaFowcStTRFFJYjgiLCJtYWMiOiJkNjc3MGM1ODc2MWM1NWFiMDBlNjYzMTg0OWI3M2RiZmNmZGU5NzU4Y2QzZDA0NmViZDQzZjIzODBiMWZiYWM1IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D
```

#2 XSRF-TOKEN:

```
eyJpdiI6Ik1xc0tCckEzS2RNNURFVWJ5aGc2Z0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidVE4TElScENjRFlEbUFtVk1sVzZ1MGU5WDI2NXk2b214aEpWbU10K1hJUGZtQzdFOFBHV3JYblZiYmlFSmQvaSt2ZWQ5cWtjOXhtZXJQTmQ0NUNSVjAvQ2xmVDNwcUw0dkRFMHZnclRSc08wanVqaHdlbGFWeE5JMk1pTzRXOFgiLCJtYWMiOiJkNzQwODAwYzU2ZGE0OTVjNzQ0MjQxNzAwZDIxMGVkNGNkZTJjNWI2NjQ2YjMzZjk4NGM1YzI4MWJhOWZmMGI2IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D
```

I'm not very experienced in reading network headers. Any idea what the problem is with the `pusher` route or how I could further debug this? Thank you in advance

## Edit:

I've tried @suxgri's approach:

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js'

Pusher.logToConsole = true

const pusher = new Pusher('bf29be46d8eb2ea8ccd4', {
  cluster: 'eu',
  forceTLS: true,
  authEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/api/pusher/auth',
  withCredentials: true,
  wsPort: 443,
  wssPort: 443,
  enableStats: false,
  enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
  auth: {
    headers: {
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'Authorization':
        'Bearer eyJpdiI6ImpCdC96YjVqNmh3VXhic0tkeXlYQ3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiN0YzMzB3QkVySDdyeFdIK0JLaXM1cWVaTDZSd3FTUkNoWHdDSEFVaTQ3ZktYMi94ak5yQVpMRkNNNjBNbWswamM0emJGa2RVRktuNU4yUXBLMUxoMU90UGxyZk94bzdUSythMlFFNmNGdFlydjdhYVI4WmlIRXk4dEdKQU9kRnYiLCJtYWMiOiIwOWI3MDg4MGZmYTAzYWY3N2QzOGM5ZmQ4MjNkMjIyNDg5OGRjZTk5YjNjNTAwZjE5MWY2YjIxZTMyMGQ3NWU0IiwidGFnIjoiIn0=',
    },
  },
})

export default pusher
```

but I still get the `401`.

Comment: It would probably better if you follow the one from [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting#client-pusher-channels) that uses laravel echo along with pusher, than just pusher alone.

Comment: What version of axios are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I tried out `laravel-echo` only to find the exact same problem. I still don't know why `pusher` and `sanctum` authorization won't work by default but modifying my `laravel-echo.js` to use a custom authorizor, made the `/api/broadcasting/auth` route work:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
import Pusher from 'pusher-js'

window.Pusher = Pusher

export default (token) => {
  return (window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'bf29be46d8eb2ea8ccd4',
    cluster: 'eu',
    forceTLS: true,
    withCredentials: true,
    authEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/api/broadcasting/auth',
    auth: {
      headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    },
    authorizer: (channel, options) => {
      return {
        authorize: (socketId, callback) => {
          axios
            .post('/api/broadcasting/auth', {
              socket_id: socketId,
              channel_name: channel.name,
            })
            .then((response) => {
              callback(null, response.data)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              callback(error)
            })
        },
      }
    },
  }))
}
```

For plain `pusher-js` it is probably `/api/pusher/auth` route, that has to be configured (if pusher-js supports custom authorizor at all).

Answer (score 0):

Laravel respond with a 401 error code because the auth:sanctum middleware stops the request as you are not sending the auth parameter (access token), please see the new line in auth -> headers below.
Then it should work or at least reach the controller and log 'test'

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js'

Pusher.logToConsole = true

const pusher = new Pusher('bf29be46d8eb2ea8ccd4', {
  cluster: 'eu',
  forceTLS: true,
  authEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/api/pusher/auth',
  withCredentials: true,
  wsPort: 443,
  wssPort: 443,
  enableStats: false,
  enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
  auth: {
    headers: {
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer your-token',
    },
  }
})

export default pusher
```

Please note the above answer is correct for mobile+api apps but not for spa+api apps.

**EDIT:**

from the Laravel docs (sanctum#spa authentiction)

> During this request, Laravel will set an XSRF-TOKEN cookie containing the current CSRF token. This token should then be passed in an X-XSRF-TOKEN header on subsequent requests, which some HTTP client libraries like Axios and the Angular HttpClient will do automatically for you. If your JavaScript HTTP library does not set the value for you, you will need to manually set the X-XSRF-TOKEN header to match the value of the XSRF-TOKEN cookie that is set by this route.

It seems like axios is not passing the XSRF-TOKEN in any of the request header you posted so i would modify as below:

```
auth: {
    headers: {
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'X-XSRF-TOKEN': 'your-token',
    },
}
```

Next i would inspect the http://localhost:8000/api/pusher/auth request to make sure the token is passed, if the problem still persists i would follow the steps in:

Laravel docs -> Sanctum -> Authorizing Private Broadcast Channels

**EDIT 2**

Pusher js send requests using the Fetch api, when using axios the credentials were set to true in the config file, but the fetch api has it set to false and using withCredentials:true does not work.

Here i found a solution, [pusher js set credentials](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js/issues/471).
(note that if you test by hardcoding the token you should omit the part after % (last 3 char)).

The code would be:

```
Pusher.Runtime.createXHR = function () {
     const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.withCredentials = true;
     return xhr;
};

const pusher = new Pusher('bf29be46d8eb2ea8ccd4', {
  cluster: 'eu',
  forceTLS: true,
  authEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/api/pusher/auth',
  //withCredentials: true,
  wsPort: 443,
  wssPort: 443,
  enableStats: false,
  enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
  auth: {
    headers: {
      'X-XSRF-TOKEN': 'your-token',
    },
  }
})

export default pusher
```

Using a custom authorizer can be done with pusher js as explained [here](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js/issues/272), or similarly with Echo.
When using a custom authorizer the authEndpoint and auth keys become unnecessary.
The authorizer is successful because axios send the required headers without additional setup.

Comment: Am I doing it right? Please see the Edit section. I'm still getting the `401`. It's the `XSRF-Token` from my backend response headers.

Comment: Hi, no you are sending the wrong token, you can get the access Token back from laravel after the login you usually save it if you want to make calls to auth routes. It in the form number|code, for example 132|slwufhcywjdjfjsjxj

Comment: I dont think I can access the authToken since im using sanctum authentication, which seems to manage the auth tokens with all https requests automatically after login. I'd try to access the token in the backend, right after authentication next and send it manually to the frontend after login to feed it to pusher. Is this a secure approach? How is this problem generally handled with Pusher?

Comment: Are you sure that the token I've used is not the right one? It gets set by sanctum in all requests in the header and passed around continuosly.

Comment: hi Artur, i am sorry you are right, my answer is ok for a sanctum (mobile+api) app and not for the spa+api app you are developing. i will look further into it and get back to you

Comment: please see the edit should fix it

Comment: I've tried your updated approach but still get the same `401`. I'm a bit lost at this point. There seems to be a problem with `pusher` and `sanctum` with my `spa`. I'll try `laravel-echo` next. I'll give you the bounty, so that it doesn't expire.

Comment: i ll check myself with a SPA and update the answer further, are you using nuxt or just vue?

Comment: I'm using `vue 3`

Comment: I'm trying to set up `laravel-echo` but getting the same `401`. It seems the broadcast route can't be authorized.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov, edited now it should be clear for both pusher js and laravel echo

Answer (score 0):

#### Reflection on your Pusher JS code

If authentication is used to access API routes, the presence and transmission of the appropriate tokens will be required for any request that involves accessing the API routes.

```js
const pusher = new Pusher('your-public-key', {
  cluster: 'eu',
  forceTLS: true,
  authEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/api/pusher/auth',
  auth: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer ${token}", // here | value of "token" can get from backend
    },
  }
})
```

- [Authorizing users](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authorizing-users/) - Pusher Docs

#### Solution with Laravel Echo

I used the Laravel Echo client package recommended by the documentation to establish broadcasting communication.

- [Client Side Installation (Pusher Channels)](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting#client-side-installation) - Laravel Docs
- [How to configure Pusher to Laravel](https://pusher.com/tutorials/typing-indicator-laravel/) - Pusher Docs
- [Laravel Echo Repository](https://github.com/laravel/echo) - GitHub

The Laravel Documentation also covers the authentication methods required for channel listening.

- [Laravel Echo Authorization Request](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting#defining-authorization-routes)

**Install the `laravel-echo` package as a development dependency** alongside the `pusher-js` package.

```
npm install --save-dev laravel-echo pusher-js
```

**Create the necessary `Echo` class on the client side** at the desired location for establishing the connection.

```js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
 
window.Pusher = Pusher;
 
window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
  cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
  forceTLS: true,
  
  // can use encrypted connection
  // encrypted: true,

  // if using Sanctum or another method for API authentication, the broadcast listener will need a valid Bearer Token, which must be passed in the header
  auth: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, // here | value of "token" can get from backend
    },
  },

  // for specifying a custom endpoint, use:
  // authEndpoint: '/custom/endpoint/auth',
  
  // for entirely custom authentication, remember to pass the token in the headers
  // authorizer: (channel, options) => { ... }
});
```

After this, by invoking the global `window.Echo`, you can connect to the channels.

```js
const inquireChatSession = () => {
  axios
    .get(`/api/chat/${props.id}`)
    .then((res) => {
      state.chatSessionId = res.data.id
      state.messages = res.data.messages
      state.loadingSession = false

      const channel = window.Echo.private(`private-chat.${state.chatSessionId}`)

      channel.listen('App\\Events\\ChatMessageSent', (event) => {
        state.messages.push(event.chatMessage)
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      state.errors = error.response.data.errors
      state.loadingSession = false
    })
}
```

I don't know your intentions, but I must point out that listening to the `channel` in your code will immediately cease once the `then()` function is executed. Therefore, it is advisable to define an external `channel` variable and write the channel listening into it when the `then()` branch is executed.

```js
let channel; // here

const inquireChatSession = () => {
  axios
    .get(`/api/chat/${props.id}`)
    .then((res) => {
      state.chatSessionId = res.data.id
      state.messages = res.data.messages
      state.loadingSession = false

      channel = window.Echo.private(`private-chat.${state.chatSessionId}`)

      channel.listen('App\\Events\\ChatMessageSent', (event) => {
        state.messages.push(event.chatMessage)
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      state.errors = error.response.data.errors
      state.loadingSession = false
    })
}
```

#### Extra

- [Information about WebSockets, Pusher, and Laravel Echo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66570018/15167500) - Stackoverflow Answer
- [More information about Bearer Token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25843058/15167500) - Stackoverflow Answer
- [How to get Bearer Token in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71740096/15167500) - Stackoverflow Answer (You can pass the token obtained in Laravel to the client in Vue using an axios get request before creating Echo.)

#### Create channel in Laravel

It is advisable to define the event according to the documentation. Afterward, you can create an event on the defined channel anywhere in the application.

- [Create Laravel Event with PrivateChannel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting#the-shouldbroadcast-interface) - Laravel Docs
- [Use Event with `event()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-event) - Laravel Docs

**app/Events/ChatMessageSent.php**

```
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ChatMessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $chatMessage;

    public function __construct($chatMessage)
    {
        $this->chatMessage = $chatMessage;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('private-chat.' . $this->chatMessage['chatSessionId']);
    }
}
```

**ChatController.php**

```
use App\Events\ChatMessageSent;

public function sendMessage(Request $request)
{
    event(new ChatMessageSent($chatMessage));

    return response()->json(['status' => 'Message sent']);
}
```

Comment: hi i think your answer is correct for a mobile+api app but not for the spa+api app as you could see from the sanctum official docs

Comment: I believe that using tokens is more common for authenticating API connections (and the question did not mention deviating from this in the response, although it is indeed not a bad idea to discuss this scenario as well). The documentation primarily addresses this aspect. In the case of SPA, the same steps need to be taken. Authentication is required to access API routes. For SPA, instead of tokens, we will use sessions (CSRF) for identification. Following the documentation, you can appropriately configure the Echo class, similar to how I did it with tokens.

Comment: yes i was just saying that in the case of spa there is no bearer token, as you can see from my answer we 'wasted' some time on it yesterday

Comment: Session-based authentication can indeed be advantageous and simpler in the case of an SPA application; however, it is always worth considering the use cases. Token-based API authentication is much more versatile, allowing a backend to potentially serve multiple frontends (websites, mobileapps, ...). The SPA approach does not preclude the use of API token-based authentication. It is up to the developer to clarify which method they will apply and why. Indeed, if the authentication relies solely on the session, establishing a proper API connection will be limited to a single frontend and backend.